# Postman - How to automate Oauth 2.0 flow request by request?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, postman, next-auth

Im struggling with automation of an Oauth 2.0 flow in Postman. I want to recreate that to run it automatically because refreshing is not working in runner or monitor. Im trying to find the endpoint which I can hit with all of the data needed. I was trying to hit :
[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenant_id}}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=&client_id=&scope=&redirect_uri=](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7B%7Btenant_id%7D%7D/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=&client_id=&scope=&redirect_uri=)
with my own data but it wont give me the bearer.
Any ideas how to solve that ?